# How do I stop a JQuery function from being called after conditions for an if else statement are reevaluated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I'm trying to create a mobile layout for my site, and I'm having trouble with the menu portion. All of my CSS works, and I've narrowed the problem down to my JQuery, specifically this:

```
var mobileNav = function(){

    if($(window).width() < 751){
        $('#mobile_nav').hide();
        toggleNav();
    } else {
        $('#mobile_nav').show();
    }

};

var toggleNav = function(){

    $('#page_nav_bar').toggle(function(){
            $('#mobile_nav').show();
    }, function(){
            $('#mobile_nav').hide();
    });

};

mobileNav();

$(window).resize(mobileNav);
```

For some reason when I resize my browser from under 751 to a larger size, the toggleNav() function doesn't stop. Even if my browser is larger than 751 after I've resized it, when I try to click the #page_nav_bar element it toggles show/hide. The other functions (hide the element when the browser is small, show it when it's large) work fine, but I can't figure out how to get toggleNav() to *stop* after the window is larger than when it was originally called.

I'm sorry if this is a simple fix. I'm relatively new to JQuery and I've been trying to figure this out for days. I've tried .on/.off to the best of my ability, toggle .noop after the else, and tried rearranging everything (originally it was all one chunk of code under the mobileNav variable).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks like it works fine when I test it. Is there more code? Quick test [here](http://jsbin.com/qaface/embed?console,output) (resize the panes and/or the browser)

Comment: Also dimensions may be incorrect when the page is zoomed by the user.

Comment: @Drakes Thanks for the quick response! I couldn't quite figure out the quick test (I'm really new to all this, sorry) but [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vd3raybayqkopj/nav.js?dl=0) is the entire .js file. I don't think there's anything else that should be messing with the code above, but I'm really not sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry this took me so long to spot, but no errors were being thrown so I didn't think much of it, but the function signature for `.toggle()` is actually

> .toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )

However, you are using it more like [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) passing in two functions as such:

```
$('#page_nav_bar').toggle(function(){
    $('#mobile_nav').show();
}, function(){
    $('#mobile_nav').hide();
});
```

Since no animation is *actually* taking place and it wasn't mentioned in the question, I'm assuming that you are not concerned with slow fade ins/outs. If this is the case, you can simplify your code more like the following:

```
// NOTE: Try to only create jQuery objects once and reuse them
$window = $(window);
$mobile_nav = $("#mobile_nav");

var mobileNav = function() {
    if ($window.width() < 751) {
        $mobile_nav.hide();
    } else {
        $mobile_nav.show();
    }
};

mobileNav();
$(window).resize(mobileNav);
```

I hope this is more what you are looking for.

**Demo:** [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/zokuja/3/embed?js,output)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Looking back at the code, I was really overthinking the problem. I guess that's what happens when I stare at the same couple of lines for way too long! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a race, you call the function everytime the resize event is dispatched by the window (that mean a lots of time during resizing). Then toggleNav(); at line4 is executed everytime as well. Sometime the DOM didnt refreshed its state that window resize callback function is called again and cause the issue you describe, to avoid this problem, i suggest you do the following:

```
resizeTimeout = null; //timeOut Timer Reference
$(document).ready(function(){ //called when Dom is ready (start up function)
    $(window).resize(function(){ 
    if(!resizeTimeout) //if there is no timeOut initialized
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ //execute this anomymous function avec 100 milliseconds
            mobileNav();
            resizeTimeout = null;
            },100);
    })
    mobileNav();
});
```

I use a setTimeout within the callback function of window.resize is for the following reason:

- It avoid calling the function ToogleNav on each resize callback (minor optimization)
- It ensure to be executed after the DOM have been refreshed its state

**you could solve this easily using css:**

```
#mobile_nav,
#mobile_nav.hidden{ display: none; } /* Hidden by default (mobile first) */
#mobile_nav.visible{ display: block } /* Visible by default only when using class="visible" */

@media (min-width: 751px  ) {
    #mobile_nav { display:block; } /* Visible by default only when the width is >= 751px */
    #mobile_nav.hidden{ display: none; } 
    #mobile_nav.visible{ display: block } class="visible" */
}
```